# Can't find what the unexpected token on React Native project

Tags: react-native

Start my app with very simple code but have `SyntaxError /Users/user/myApp/index.ios.js: Unexpected token (7:6)`.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text } from 'react-native';

class HelloWorldApp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Text>Hello world!</Text>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('HelloWorldApp', () => HelloWorldApp);
```

Can't understand where is my mistake. I tried `rm -rf node_modules` and `npm install`, tried `npm chache clen` and `watchman watch-del-all` but still get error.

Comment: Are you sure you're executing correct index.ios.js? The syntax error mentions path /Users/user/myApp/index.ios.js, but your project is initialized as HelloWorldApp. Thus the default path should be Users/user/HelloWorldApp/index.ios.js.

Comment: Yes, I am sure, `index.ios.js` is correct

Comment: Hi, did you solve the error?

Answer (score 1):

I got this when I had accidently added a .babelrc file from another project. Removed it and the packager started working again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your Text component with a `View`.  `<Text>` cannot be used as a root component

Comment: Hi! Thank you for answer, but nothing change (

Comment: Have you imported a View from react-native?